# Validating presence and content type for the same property test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

Here is my model in Ruby on rails

```
 class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :medium => "400x400>", :thumb => "100x100>", :square =>       "300x300#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_presence_of(:description, :color, :category, :size, :image)
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and I am trying to test it using rspec and factory girl overriding image property from model in test. But I cannot, because nil doesn't full fill content type validation - it has to be an image. As a result we can either test if it's an image, or if it's included.

```
describe Item, type: :model do

  context "validations" do
    let(:user) {create(:user)}
    subject(:item) {
      create(:item, user_id: user.id)
    }

  it "is not valid without an image" do
      item[:image] = nil
      expect(item).not_to be_valid
    end
  end
end


include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :item do
    size "XS"
    color "Orange"
    category "Onesie"
    description "Pokemon onesie"
    image { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'files', 'images', 'pokemon_onesie.jpg'), 'image/png') }
    user_id 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out it was quite simple

```
it "is not valid without an image" do
  expect{item[:image] = nil}.to raise_error(NameError)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the README [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) you can use a single validator statement for multiple validations. Something like this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :medium => "400x400>", :thumb => "100x100>", :square =>       "300x300#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_presence_of(:description, :color, :category, :size)
  validates_attachment :image,
    content_type: { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
    presence: true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: still don't know how to test it